# How to filter a carousel created with nested ng-repeat with custom filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created a carousel through `ng-repeat` with 8 slides. Each slide contains 12 icons. Means 96 icons are divided in 8 slide with 12 icons per slide.

Now I put input text field with `ng-model` for custom filter by name of icon.

Filter is not working properly i.e. when I put any string in input box, it filter the icons through all 8 slides, but it also show the slide with blank which it didn't find any matching icon. I need to update the carousel with filter result.

i.e : if user input 'and' in input text, and it matches in slide 1,5,9 only then carousel should updated with 3 matching slides 1,5,9 and rest of the slides should be removed from DOM.

How to do it in angularjs ? Please help me.

You can see working demo here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/T0oLp0nG52iPslpa7z9s?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Angular can actually do it for u. You can try to do filter in each of your row. Try to input "a" to test.

```js
const App = angular.module("a", []);

App.controller("test", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    ["abc", "bcd", "cde", "def", ],
    ["bcd", "cde", "def", "efg", ]
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="a">
  <div ng-controller="test">
    <input ng-model="search">
    <div ng-repeat="row in data | filter:search" style="height:30px;background:antiquewhite;">
      <span  ng-repeat="d in row | filter:search" ng-bind="d" style="margin-right:10px;">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried with you code but it is also not giving me exact result.
What exactly I need is to update slides according to the text matches in input box and the slides which doesn't match with input text should be washed off from DOM.

Comment: It's my fault, sorry.@user3744780